# Al tratar de redireccionar a otra pagina con github pages me lanza un error y no me redirecciona

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

Este el JavaScript para redireccionar, en local me funciona pero en github pages  me lanza un error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error que lanza al tratar de redirreccionar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrian dar una mano por favor?

---

Este es el error que lanza en la consola del navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen del codigo donde se ejcuta el window.location.replace

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿`http` o `https`? Además, pon el mensaje de error y el código _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden visualizar las imágenes.

Comment: Estuve probando ambos, con http y https, obtengo el mismo error

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega los cambios correspondientes _en la pregunta_. De nuevo: **pon el mensaje de error y el código _como texto, con formato_, ya que [no todos pueden visualizar las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976)**.